# How did they make the stickies in this blog?

Tags: css, graphics, webkit

I'm wondering how the people at Panic made the stickies in their blog page!!!

http://www.panic.com/blog/

I got the 3d trasformation, but i really can't understand how they did the moving shadow!

any idea?

(Warning: webkit browser needed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just look at the source. They scaled the shadow up (vertically) by 2%.

```
#features ul li:hover div {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
}
```

The origin and css transition was set in an earlier declaration.

```
#features ul li div { /* fake blank div included at the start of each out; it holds the shadow */
    width: 225px;
    height: 210px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .4s ease; 
}
```